# Glassfish JAX-WS side by side SSL / insecure EJB webservice

Tags: web-services, glassfish, ejb-3.0, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

Is it possible to run a single @WebService bean as both secure and insecure at the same time, preferably using the same URL except for the http/https protocol difference?

I am able to run the service either secure or insecure using:

```
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
```

or

```
<transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
```

inside sun-ejb-jar.xml

IE.

```
<ejb>
  <ejb-name>MyEJB</ejb-name>
  <webservice-endpoint>
    <port-component-name>MyWebService</port-component-name>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </webservice-endpoint>
</ejb>
```

Suggestions?

Comment: I am not clear on the details... so I won't submit this as an answer... You may want to dig into the topic of Grizzly port unification.  It seems like that will allow you to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks vkraemer I will have a look at that.

Comment: What happens with <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee> and a http SSL enabled listener? NONE doesn't preclude SSL from also working.

The other option if you can install apache, httpd w/mod_ssl + mod_jk/ajp would probably work.

Comment: @Chase unfortunately with NONE it will only route from the unsecure listener. mod_ssl is definitely the way to go in any production scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Why you just not proxy app server with Apache HTTP server or similar? I usually do this way and leave SSL handshaking/open text connection to HTTP in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>`, your beans will be available on http and https also.
`<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>` means strict security, any http request coming is redirected to https(ssl).

removing this `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>` you will get great flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that this is a pretty old question. However, I feel like providing this answer since I recently ran into the exact same issue.

According to Oracle documentation:

> - Specify CONFIDENTIAL when the application requires that data be transmitted so as to prevent other entities from observing the contents of the transmission.
> - Specify NONE to indicate that the container must accept the constrained requests on any connection, including an unprotected one.

Since this is merely a transport-guarantee, a NONE value should provide you the feature you want, namely an EJB Web Service responding both to http and https requests.

The problem here is a bug in Glassfish that apparently restricts you to either accept http OR https requests to your EJB Web Service:

- Bug in Glassfish 2.x: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-5621
- Bug in Glassfish 3.x: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-19293

According to the last jira task the issue should be fixed and working from Glassfish 4.0_b75.